# YAML parsing error. Expected <block end>, but found '-'

Tags: build, yaml, integration, filepath, circleci

I have the following config.yml:

```
    - persist_to_workspace:
        root: ~/project
        paths: *build_cache_paths
         # for integration tests:
        - /home/circleci/cache/Cypress
```

I'm trying to persist_to_workspace `/home/circleci/cache/Cypress`. What's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `paths` key has the value `*build_cache_paths` which is an alias. That means the value of `paths` is a reference to the node with the anchor `&build_cache_paths` (assuming it exists).

Two lines below, you start a sequence with `-`. Generally, a sequence at this level would be the value of a previous implicit key. But in this case it can't be, since the key `paths` already has a value. Hence the error.

If your goal is to merge the sequence behind `*build_cache_paths` with the sequence you give below: That is not possible with YAML. YAML is a serialization language, it doesn't implement operations on data (apart from the non-standard merge key `<<` that is supported by some implementations but only works on mappings, not on sequences).